# Managed to format Mysql timestamp to UK date format but can't get time included

Tags: php, mysql

I managed to format mysql timestamp to UK date format but don't know how to get time included.

This is the code:

```
        <b><?php echo date("d F Y",strtotime($row['notedate']));?></b><br>
```

This outputs

```
13 December 2015
```

The above is perfect UK format, but how can I include time as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Include `H:i:s`? -> `<?php echo date("d F Y H:i:s",strtotime($row['notedate']));?>`?

Comment: Can you try this?

`<b><?php echo date("d F Y H:i:s",strtotime($row['notedate']));?></b><br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the other answers in the comments, if you use H:i:s it will print out

```
16:23:12
```

for example, you could use am/pm as most people in the UK prefer this time format ( I believe ) which would be:

```
date("d F Y g:i A",strtotime($row['notedate']));
```

to give you:

```
13 December 2015 05:58 AM
```

All of the different time and date formats can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Thanks for that. Worked like a charm.